# FireStore anyQuery.onComplete() will always run on main thread ? That's weird

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
class ExampleThread extends  Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "ExampleThread->run: currentThread= " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            db.collection("PointsAndRating")
                    .orderBy("gmq", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "ExampleThread->run: currentThread= " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + "=accumulatedUpdatedNugget=@@ => " + document.getData());
                    } // end of for loop
                }
            });
        }
    } // end of ExampleThread
```

Unfortunately, line  `Log.d(TAG, "ExampleThread->run: currentThread= " + Thread.currentThread().getId());` is returning 1.

Answer (score 2):

The Firestore SDK handles all its network and disk interactions in a separate thread. But all callbacks to your code are made on the main thread, so that you can interact with the UI from them.